What is the practical difference between `writeHtml5` and `writeHtml5string`?
It seems that the writeHtml5 produces a structure, which can be rendered with Blaze. writeHtml5string produces Text.
I looked at the code but cannot understand if there is a difference to call writeHtml5string or combine writeHtml5 and renderHtml from Blaze. Are there cases where one or the other is advisable? Is the option with Blaze faster?

writeHtml5string is the function pandoc uses itself for the cli, so if you need a Text in the end, that's what I'd use. It calls renderHtml', which is implemented as:
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Text (renderHtml)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL

renderHtml' :: Html -> Text
renderHtml' = TL.toStrict . renderHtml

If you want to add the HTML snippet to another Blaze document, then you should use writeHtml5 instead.
